# POSTGRESQL Refresh materialized views CONCURRENTLY

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

How to speed up refresh of simple materilized view
`create materialized view some_name as select * from some_heavy_table WITH DATA`
if it took a lot of time being refreshed CONCURRENTLY?

Comment: `CONCURRENTLY` is about not blocking other connections not being fast. If you want faster drop the `CONCURRENTLY` at the expense of blocking concurrent selects.

Comment: unfortunately, it is our aim- to prevent blocks in database by using refresh concurrently. But it works so long for 50 GB table

Comment: You cannot have both. Everything is a trade off. The trade off for `CONCURRENTLY` is time. *Pick one*.

Comment: Why not just query the 50GB table directly?

Comment: Your question is as unanswerable as "how to make my database faster". It lacks details like definitions, measurements and execution plans.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [performance of refreshing postgres materialized view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63403582/performance-of-refreshing-postgres-materialized-view)

Answer (score 2):

From the Postgres [source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/b0a55e43299c4ea2a9a8c757f9c26352407d0ccc/src/backend/commands/matview.c#L283) code:

> Concurrent refresh builds new data in temp tablespace, and does diff

So refreshing a materialized view concurrently will take more time, because there is more work to do. Instead of just replacing the table, it has to check for the difference between old and new and update. In both cases the data from the query needs to be computed, but there's no way around that, and basically no difference between using 'concurrently' or not.

However, anything depending on the materialized view being available is blocked unless you use 'concurrently'. So if you have a long running refresh, it might be beneficial to do it concurrently. This will take more time in total, but it will have less impact on the other users of the materialized view.

If your goal is to have it done as quickly as possible however, you should not use concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

On Databases `Materialized Views` only for that if your query executed a long time. It is often used on reports. How works Materialized Views?
When you create a materialized view, then DB is firstly executed your query one time and stores return data in the internal system hidden tables. Next time when we will use this view then DB will be used data stored on the system tables. That's why next time our query returns data very very fastly. Some people always use Refresh Materialized when selecting the view process. This is not the right method. In this case, there is no point in using materialized. Note that, if your data on tables used in materialized views will be updated, so you can not view updated data for selecting materialized. Because materialized views are executed and are calculated only one time. So, for viewing new data we can do refreshing materialized using `refresh materialized` commands. So, recommended using materialized only for tables which not often updated. As a result, recommended refreshing materialized views one time on the day using the jobs (or schedule scripts). And the second way is is that, you can think of some mechanism or logical process for refreshing. For example: When your data is updated then we can insert log data to our log tables, so that we knew about this updating process. And before selecting materialized views we must check our log tables, when we view the updated process records on the log tables, then we must firstly execute `refresh materialized` and after then we can use this view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We understand the purpose of mat.view, but the main question regarding speed is still on the agenda.